# Recording sound into bytestream in Android

Tags: android, audio, byte, recording

I want create an app which records a sound into bytestream and it can be listened again. It will not save the recorded audio into a file, rather it will save it into a hardware memory. And a play option will be there by which the recorded file can be played. Recorded system will be like talking tom: record the audio and play it instantly

Can anyone provide me a sample code for this functions ?

Comment: What you're talking about isn't exactly straightforward. I doubt anyone is just going to be willing to given you the entire code for it. What have you tried? Where have you looked? What have you already done towards writing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without saving the audio into a file, you can use the [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class which lets you read the recorded audio into a byte array.

An easier option to code and use would be the [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html), although it will come with a loss in performance as it does save the audio into a file every time.